# NDSolve doesn't solve my system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

What is causing the error in this code?

```
N0 = 4; μ = 2; ρ = 1; d = 1; n = 1;
eqone = Flatten[
           Join[
             Table[x[i]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[i][t]^2)*x[i]'[t] - x[i][t] + d (z[t] - x[i][t]), 
                   {i, 0, N0}], 
             {z'[t] == ρ*d/n (Sum[x[i][t] - z[t], {i, 0, N0}])}, z[0]==0,   
             x[0][0] == 1, x[0]'[0] == .5, x[N0/2][0] == 0, x[N0/2]'[0] == 0},
             Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
             Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}],
             Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}], 
             Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}]
               ]
               ]
```

and once I get my equations, I should be able to solve the differential equation, but it isn't working. I get a message that starts out:

> The function value is not a list of numbers with dimensions ...

I think I have to flatten something again in the NDSolve, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that and why.

```
eqtwo = NDSolve[eqone, {Table[x[i], {i, 0, N0}],z}, {t, 100}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a combination of simple errors. If I give ϵ a value (I used 0.1), and fix some delimiter errors in `eqone` and add `z` properly to the list of unknowns in `eqtwo`, I get a solution.

```
N0 = 4; μ = 2; ρ = 1; d = 1; n = 1; ϵ = 0.1;

eqone = Flatten[
   Join[Table[
     x[i]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[i][t]^2)*x[i]'[t] - x[i][t] + 
       d (z[t] - x[i][t]), {i, 0, N0}],
    {z'[t] == ρ*d/n (Sum[x[i][t] - z[t], {i, 0, N0}]), z[0] == 0,
     x[0][0] == 1, x[0]'[0] == .5,
     x[N0/2][0] == 0, x[N0/2]'[0] == 0},
    Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
    Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
    Table[x[i]'[0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}], 
    Table[x[i][0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}]]];

eqtwo = NDSolve[eqone, Append[Table[x[i], {i, 0, N0}], z], {t, 100}]
```

> {{x[0]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>],
> x[1]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>],
> x[2]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>],
> x[3]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>],
> x[4]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>],
> z->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.}},<>]}}

#### Edit

The OP asked for more info about `Append`. This is a basic *Mathematica*  function. I recommend reading the Wolfram docs on [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Append.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a lot. :)